# Using Regex to find longest consecutive match in a string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to achieve the following with regex:

> String =
> "APPLEORANGEORANGEAPPLEAPPLEAPPLEBANANABANANABANANAAPPLEBANANA"

If the match is

> re.compile = ["APPLE"]

The output should be 3, since that is the longest consecutive match.

Meaning, I want the other two occurrences of "APPLE" that are not consecutive or are not the longest consecutive batch to be ignored. If there are only single, separated matches, the output should be 1, since none are consecutive.

I couldn't find any filter in the documentation that only matches consecutive results, sorry if this is a beginner question and I haven't realized a feature.

Comment: the longest consecutive matches are 3 instead of 4 or not? and there are 5 apples in total, correct?

Comment: You fail to show a [mre] - your regex itself is not anywhere near finding "APPLE" in any text, you are using alternate character matches (if you add single ' before the [ and after the ] - currently you try to assign a _list_ to re.compile() - which is a *function* that you call with parameters and not something that you assign a pattern to. Beside that your pattern  does not enforce that these letters come in exactly those amount and that order - you would need a literal word match instead.

Comment: `re.comile` is a function, you are overwriting the function with a list.

Comment: So in short this is not even python and far from how python regex _would_ be used....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for all matches of one or more consecutive occurrences of the string 'APPLE', which the following regex will do:

```
(?:APPLE)+
```

[See RegEx demo](https://regex101.com/r/5LfSIi/2/)

Then you sort them in descending order by length. Take the longest match (i.e., the first match) and divide by 5 (the number of characters in 'APPLE') and that will tell you how many consecutive occurrences of 'APPLE` were found in the longest match:

```python
import re

s = "APPLEORANGEORANGEAPPLEAPPLEAPPLEBANANABANANABANANAAPPLEBANANA"
matches = sorted(re.findall(r'(?:APPLE)+', s), reverse=True)
if matches:
    print(len(matches[0]) // 5)
else:
    print(0)
```

Prints:

```
3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for. 

One question, what do you mean with the longest match being the first match? For example, what if there was a consecutive sequence of APPLEAPPLE in the beginning of the string, but then a sequence of 4 times APPLE later on, would this still work?

Answer (score 1):

Booboo has already provided an optimal solution, but as I wrote this before I noticed I'll post it anyway.

```py
import re

def get_max_consecutive_match_count(word, text):
  if word and text:
    pattern = re.compile(f'(?:{re.escape(word)})+')
    lengths = [m.end() - m.start() for m in re.finditer(pattern, text)]
    return max(lengths) // len(word) if lengths else 0

str = 'APPLEORANGEORANGEAPPLEAPPLEAPPLEBANANABANANABANANAAPPLEBANANA'

print(get_max_consecutive_match_count('APPLE', str))
```

Comment: I would propose two changes:  First, `str` is a builtin class, so I would use a different name for this argument. Second, atgument `substr` could have characters that have special meaning when used in a regular expression, such as `[`,. So I would use `pattern = re.compile(f'(?:{re.escape(substr)})+')`. You could also modify the code to only divide by `len(substr)` once.

Comment: It's *no big deal*, but to do just one division you could do: `lengths = [m.end() - m.start() for m in matches]; return max(lengths) // len(word) if lengths else 0`.

Comment: @Booboo Yep, agreed, it's an improvement.